# is windows azure installable on my own hardware?

Tags: azure, cloud

I just want to know if it is possible to install **windows azure or any other cloud technology**  on your own hardware, or the only possibility to use it is to use the Microsoft's hosting ?

**is IBM Cloud Burst a cloud OS that you can install on your own hardware ?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Microsoft have released Windows Azure Services for Windows Server - https://www.microsoft.com/hosting/en/us/services.aspx. Now you can install basically the whole Azure control panel and IaaS platform on your own Windows Server 2012 boxes/VMs.

Update: Windows Azure Services has been renamed [Windows Azure Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/windows-azure-pack/default.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to install Windows Azure on your own hardware as Azure itself is intrinsically bound to the cloud (i.e. MS data centers), however, with the Azure SDK there is software which emulates the services within the cloud primarily for development.

Comment: is there something else that can be installed on my own hardware ? (like if the government of a country want's to use cloud-computing, they want to put it on their own hardware, not in some unknown place)

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that it is available yet, but it will be possible eventually:

http://computerworld.co.nz/news.nsf/devt/CC7A4625BFF11727CC257573006E581B

You can run IBM cloudburst on your own hardware

http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/cloudburst/

Comment: what about IBM CloudBurst, is this a cloud os that you can install on your own server ?

Comment: I found WMWare VSphere, it looks like a real cloud, it can run anything

Answer (score 1):

For Windows Azure there is the [Windows Azure platform AppFabric](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/appfabric/) which helps developers connect applications and services in the cloud or on-premises. This includes applications running on Windows Azure, Windows Server and a number of other platforms including Java, Ruby, PHP and others. It provides a Service Bus for connectivity across network and organizational boundaries, and Access Control for federated authorization as a service.

There is also the "Windows Server AppFabric" which is a set of integrated technologies that make it easier to build, scale and manage Web and composite applications that run on IIS available at msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849.aspx

Answer (score 1):

JUST ANNOUNCED: Fujitsu Launches Global Cloud Platform Service Powered by Windows Azure
http://bit.ly/isBwzm

### Azure Appliance

If you are talking about Private Cloud there are few you can do.

But with respect to Azure in your own Hardware or Installing Azure in your data center, even that is **not possible** . There is something which Microsoft is coming up which is called as Azure Appliance. They are planned to be sold by eBay, Dell, Fujitsu and HP.

References

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/appliance/

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/appliance/default.aspx

http://www.silicon.com/technology/it-services/2010/07/13/windows-azure-microsoft-launches-private-cloud-offering-39746088/